# Why am I getting this error even though I don't even access this folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I run this:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clips = []
path = r'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\ResultFolder'
for file in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        clips.append(file)
           
clip = ImageSequenceClip(clips, fps = 4) 
clip.write_videofile("video.mp4", fps = 24)
```

Or this

```
from moviepy.editor import *
s = 2.5
clips = []
path = r'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\ResultFolder'
for file in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        clips.append(ImageClip(file).set_duration(s))
    
video_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
video_clip.write_videofile("video-output.mp4", fps=24, remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

I get the same error :
`"FileNotFoundError: No such file:'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\a0.1.jpg'"`

Even though I get all my images from "ResultFolder" and not the "Prog" folder. And from I can observe not even touch the "Prog" folder. One detail I might add; as to why this might be happening is that the "Prog" folder; is the folder in which I wrote the code.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Full Error:
1st one :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\reddit-bot\sheesh.py", line 10, in <module>
    clip = ImageSequenceClip(clips, fps = 4)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ImageSequenceClip.py", line 82, in __init__
    size = imread(sequence[0]).shape
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 265, in imread
    reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 172, in get_reader
    request = Request(uri, "r" + mode, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._parse_uri(uri)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 260, in _parse_uri
    raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\a0.1.jpg'
PS C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog>
```

2nd one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\reddit-bot\sheesh.py", line 8, in <module>
    clips.append(ImageClip(file).set_duration(s))
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 889, in __init__
    img = imread(img)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 265, in imread
    reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 172, in get_reader
    request = Request(uri, "r" + mode, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._parse_uri(uri)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 260, in _parse_uri
    raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\a0.1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Here it is :

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clips = []
path = r'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\ResultFolder'
for file in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        clips.append(path + "/" + file)

clip = ImageSequenceClip(clips, fps = 4) 
clip.write_videofile("video.mp4", fps = 24)
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: From this: 
```clips.append(file)```
To this :
```clips.append(path + "/" + file)```
What  was happening before was that I was giving the information of the file to the append path without it being 'complete', so it tried to that for me by concatenating it somewhere and that is here :
```'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\a0.1.jpg'```
Basically it was adding the "a0.1.jpg" to the path of the folder in which I was working with, as, I did not specify any other path, but as I added this to the code: "path + "/"" now it was 'adding' to the folder from "path". I hope that makes sense.